# ghost statament color in Dafny on Visual Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, dafny

Could I configure the color (grey, by default) of Ghost Statements in Dafny. I mean, the current gray color is too dark, it is difficult to see the text in the classroom screen. I think a lighter gray would be better.

Comment: I think it makes more sense to file this as an issue on Github https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/issues

Comment: I think https://github.com/dafny-lang/ide-vscode/issues is right place to file this issue

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to fix this.

1. Don't use markGhostStatements. By default dafny.markGhostStatements is set to be true. Change extension setting to false.
2. Use markGhostStatements, but change background color. There is no configuration to set it. Probably file an issue at https://github.com/dafny-lang/ide-vscode to provide that configuration. You can locally build ide-vscode by setting this [option](https://github.com/dafny-lang/ide-vscode/blob/be6ee7b9dc626401c414d24c32924f6735cf4cf2/src/ui/ghostDiagnosticsView.ts#L13). See images below for change in background color by setting GhostDecoration.

[image]

[image]